# On Session Timeout My page is not getting refreshed - MVC 4 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have already set the session time in `web.Config` file, after the session time out I want my page automatically to get refreshed and redirect to Login page, but its not happening, kindly find my code as mentioned below :- Pleaes help me , I have  been trying since almost 1 week, but no progress.

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

if (ctx.Session != null)
{
    // check if a new session id was generated
    if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
    {
        HttpContext ctx1 = HttpContext.Current;
        // check  sessions here
        if (ctx.Session["UserName"] == null || !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Authentication/Logon");
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have your `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` executed? Check if `Session["UserName"]` has value at the timeout period, if it's not null then `Request.IsAuthenticated` never get checked.

Answer (score 0):

The session times out only on the server. Your page will never gets refreshed automatically. You need to implement a polling mechanism from the browser to check for session availability and refresh accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much, Could you please help me how do I do that ?

Comment: See the correct answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433042/how-to-detect-mvc-3-session-expiration-via-javascript