# Check If a User Session Is Active in ASP.Net Application Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC Application using SimpleMembership and I want to create a SetInterval function that checks if the user ASP.Net session is still active from the Javascript and if not redirect them to another page.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the question? Can you show us your existing attempt at the Javascript?

Comment: How do I check using javascript if a Users session in an ASP.Net application is active or expired?

I've looked at some other example and they seem to user PHP to do this, I wanted to know how to write something (if its possible) to see if the session is expired.

I don't have any Javascript at the moment to do this

Comment: possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433042/how-to-detect-mvc-3-session-expiration-via-javascript

Comment: @DanNguyen yes thats pretty much exactly what I was looking, thanks very much.  I really need to get better at searching

Comment: With help from @DanNguyen the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433042/how-to-detect-mvc-3-session-expiration-via-javascript)