# prevent session timeout in older tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, session, timeout

I have an ASP.NET web application with an angular REST client, every user works on multiple tabs for long periods of time and session is timing out (inactivity) even if the user is active on the second tab.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

increasing session timeout is not a solution since users can be inactive in the tab but active in the browser up to 4 hours.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean "session is timing out?" There is only one ASP.NET session that spans all tabs, and if they're active in any of them, it should not be expiring. I think you mean "a session timeout warning is being displayed in older tabs even when the session is not yet timing out," which will be an implementation-specific problem (meaning-- show your code).

Comment: "There is only one ASP.NET session that spans all tabs, and if they're active in any of them, it should not be expiring". This is not happening. But you are right, is my implementation. I'm closing the session myself after the "session is about to expire warning":(. Thank's John. Please answer the question so I can set it as accepted.

Comment: The question now is how to know if session is active in another tab. But It can wait til monday XD. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433042/how-to-detect-mvc-3-session-expiration-via-javascript